# Keras callbacks when running cross validation

Tags: keras

I've read that you can't do cross-validation with Keras when you also want to use model callbacks, but then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492824/can-i-send-callbacks-to-a-kerasclassifier) showed that it was possible after all. However, I'm having a hard time incorporating this in my context.

To explore this in more detail, I am following the [machinelearningmastery blog](http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/), and using [the iris dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data).

This is a three-class classification problem, and I'm attempting to use a multilayer perceptron (one layer for now, for testing). My goal right now is to work in model callbacks so I can save the weights of the best model. Below, I attempt that in my section `network_mlp`. To show that the model works without callbacks, I also include `network_mlp_no_callbacks`.

You should be able to copy/paste this into a python session and run it, no problem. To replicate the error I'm seeing, uncomment the last line.

Error: `RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x7f7e1c9d2290>, as the constructor does not seem to set parameter callbacks`

Code: first section reads in the data; second is the model with callbacks, which is not working; third is the model without callbacks, which works (to provide context).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pandas, math, sys, keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

def read_data_mlp(train_file):
   train_data = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
   train_data = train_data.values
   X = train_data[:,0:4].astype(float)
   Y = train_data[:,4]
   X = X.astype('float32')

   scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

   # encode class values as integers
   encoder = LabelEncoder()
   encoder.fit(Y)
   encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
   # convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
   dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

   X_train_s = scaler.fit_transform(X)

   return (X_train_s, dummy_y)

def network_mlp(X, Y, out_dim=10, b_size=30, num_classes=3, epochs=10):
   #out_dim is the dimensionality of the hidden layer;
   #b_size is the batch size. There are 150 examples total.

   filepath="weights_mlp.hdf5"

   def mlp_model():
           model = Sequential()
           model.add(Dense(out_dim, input_dim=4, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
           model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
           model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
           return model

   checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
   callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
   estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mlp_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=b_size, verbose=0, callbacks=callbacks_list)
   kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
   results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
   print("MLP: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))

   return 0

def network_mlp_no_callbacks(X, Y, out_dim=10, b_size=30, num_classes=3, epochs=10):

   def mlp_model():
           model = Sequential()
           model.add(Dense(out_dim, input_dim=4, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
           model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
           model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
           return model

   estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mlp_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=b_size, verbose=0)
   kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
   results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
   print("MLP: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))

   return 0

if __name__=='__main__':

   X, Y = read_data_mlp('iris.csv')
   network_mlp_no_callbacks(X, Y, out_dim=10, b_size=30, num_classes=3, epochs = 10)
   #network_mlp(X, Y, out_dim=10, b_size=30, num_classes=3, epochs = 10)
```

QUESTION: How can I incorporate model callbacks into KerasClassifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is fairly close to the other answer you referenced, but slightly different because they are using several estimators and you have only one. I was able to get checkpointing working by adding `fit_params={'callbacks': callbacks_list}` to the `cross_val_score` call, removing the callback list from the `estimator` initialization, and changing `save_best_only` to `False`.

So now the subsection of code in `network_mlp` looks like this:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mlp_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=b_size, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold, fit_params={'callbacks': callbacks_list})
```

`save_best_only=False` is necessary because you don't have a validation split set up for the neural network, and thus `val_acc` is unavailable. If you want to use a validation sub-split, you can for example change the estimator initialization to:

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=mlp_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=b_size, verbose=0, validation_split=.25)
```

Good luck!