# How to save Keras model with best parameters using GridSearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Is there any way I can save the full Keras model with best parameters obtained using Gridsearch.

I have the following Keras model:

```
def create_model(init_mode='uniform'):
    n_x_new=train_selected_x.shape[1]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n_x_new, input_dim=n_x_new, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.8))

    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation='sigmoid'))


    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)


model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=30, batch_size=400, verbose=1)

init_mode = ['uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'normal', 'zero', 'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform']
param_grid = dict(init_mode=init_mode)
#cv = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=my_test_fold)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,scoring='roc_auc',cv = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=my_test_fold), n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(np.concatenate((train_selected_x, test_selected_x), axis=0), np.concatenate((train_selected_y, test_selected_y), axis=0))



print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

I came to know that I can use `callback` and `checkpoint` method, but I don't know where to put the required code for this method in my original code.

The code I came across while researching is as follows.

```
filepath="weights.best.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, it seems it has to be as simple as

```
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=DNN, nb_epoch=32, batch_size=8, callbacks=[your_callback], verbose=1)
```

But that does't seem to work too.
A possible workaround comes from an answer given for - [Can I send callbacks to a KerasClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492824/can-i-send-callbacks-to-a-kerasclassifier), which should help.

> This comes as consequence to using different general tools that
>   weren't especially thought to be used together with all the possible
>   configurations.

Also, you can refer to this ticket - [How to pass callbacks to scikit_learn wrappers (e.g. KerasClassifier) #4278](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4278#issuecomment-258922449)

Hope it helps!