# Use early stopping - gridsearchcv - kerasregressor

Tags: keras, callback, regression, gridsearchcv, early-stopping

This is my question: How can I use early stopping in my code? Which part should I put it?

```
callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10,mode="auto")]
```

My code:

```
numpy.random import seed
seed(1)

def create_model(optimizer='rmsprop'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer = optimizer)

    return model

clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model,epochs = 500,callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( patience=10)])

param_grid = {
'clf__optimizer' : ['adam','rmsprop'],
'clf__batch_size' : [500,45,77]
}

pipeline = Pipeline([
('clf',clf)
])

from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, cv=tscv,param_grid=param_grid,return_train_score=True,verbose=10,
scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')

grid.fit(Xtrain2,ytrain.values)

grid.cv_results_
```

I put callbacks in 'grid.fit' and also in 'param_grid' but I got error!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use train the keras model directly using `model.fit()` function and you will see it allows you to pass in a callbacks parameter

Comment: I don't have problem use early stopping in `model.fit()` ,but I insist on using cross-validation to avoid over fitting so I have to use `gridsearchcv` .Is there any ways to use   both `gridsearchcv` and  `early_stopping` ??

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are specified in `KerasRegressor.fit` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)), and `GridSearchCV.fit` admits `fit_params` keyword arguments.  From [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit):

> ****fit_params : *dict of str -> object***
>
> Parameters passed to the `fit` method of the estimator

So something along the lines of

```py
grid.fit(Xtrain2, ytrain.values, callbacks=[...])
```

should generally work.  In your case, because you've embedded inside a pipeline, you need to additionally scope to the model, as

```py
grid.fit(Xtrain2, ytrain.values, clf__callbacks=[...])
```

See also [Can I send callbacks to a KerasClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42492824/10495893), though there are a lot of other issues in that question.