# Understanding what RandomizedSearchCV + KerasClassifier do when training

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network, gridsearchcv

I have a training set on which I would like to train a neural network, using K-folds cross validation.

**TL;DR:** Given the number of `epochs`, the set of `params` to be used, and checking on the test-set, how `RandomizedSearchCV` trains the model? I would think that for a combination of params, it trains the model on (K-1) folds for `epochs` number of epochs. Then it tests it on the last fold. But then, what prevent us from overfitting? When "vanilla" training with a constant validation set, after each epoch `keras` checks it on the validation set, is it done here as well? Even though `verbose=1` I don't see the scores from the fit on the remaining fold. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492824/can-i-send-callbacks-to-a-kerasclassifier) that we can add `callbacks` to the `KerasClassifier`, but then, what happens if the settings of `KerasClassifier` and `RandomizedSearchCV` clash? Can I add there a callback to check the `val_prc`, for exampl? If so, what would happen?

**Sorry for the long TL;DR!**

Regarding the training procedure, I am using the `keras-sklearn` interface. I defined the model using

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model_, epochs=120, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

Where `get_model_` is a function that returns a compiled `tf.keras` model.

Given the model, the training procedure is the following:

```
params = dict({'l2':[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.8],
               'dropout_rate':[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.8],
               'batch_size':[16,32,64,128],
               'learning_rate':[0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1]})


def trainer(model, X, y, folds, params, verbose=None):
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
    
    if not verbose:
        v=0
    else:
      v = verbose
    
    clf = RandomizedSearchCV(model, 
                         param_distributions = params, 
                         n_jobs = 1, 
                         scoring="roc_auc",
                         cv = folds, 
                         verbose = v)
    # -------------- fit ------------
    grid_result = clf.fit(X, y)
    # summarize results
    
    print('- '*40)
    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
    print('- '*40)

# ------ Training -------- #
trainer(model, X_train, y_train, folds, params, verbose=1)
```

First, do I use `RandomizedSearchCV` right? Regardless of the number of options for each `param` I get the same message: `Fitting 5 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 50 fits`
Second, I have a hard problem with imbalanced data + lack of data. Even so, I get unexpectedly low scores and high `loss` values.
Lastly, and following the TL;DR, what is the training procedure that is actually being done using the above code, assuming that it is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> First, do I use RandomizedSearchCV right? Regardless of the number of options for each param I get the same message: Fitting 5 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 50 fits

RandomizedSearchCV has an argument `n_iter` that defaults to 10, it will thus sample 10 configurations of parameters, no matter how many possible ones are there. If you want to run **all combinations** you want to use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) instead.

> Second, I have a hard problem with imbalanced data + lack of data. Even so, I get unexpectedly low scores and high loss values.

This is way too broad / ill posed question for stack overflow.

> Lastly, and following the TL;DR, what is the training procedure that is actually being done using the above code, assuming that it is correct.

```
For i=1 to n_iters (10):

    Get random hyperparameters from provided space
    Split data into 5 equal chunks (X_1, y_1), ..., (X_5, y_5)

    scores = []
    for k=1 to 5:
       Train model with given hyperparameters on all chunks apart from (X_k, y_k)
       Evaluate the above model on (X_k, y_k)
       Append score to scores
    
    if avg(scores) > best_score:
      best_score = avg(scores)
      best_model = model
      best_hyperparameters = hyperparameters
```